# Is there a way to install Delphi 2010 on Windows 2000

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, windows-server-2000

I just downloaded the Delphi 2010 iso from my SA-subscription and wanted to install it in addition to my other Delphi installations on my notebook computer. Unfortunately it refuses to install because the machine is running Windows 2000.

Is it possible somehow to get it to install it anyway? Or is there a technical reason why it might not work, even if it installed?

edit:

Some more information:

- Delphi 2009 installed fine on that computer, so dotNET 2.0 is already installed.
- The Delphi 2010 installer comes up, asks me for the language to use and then says "This product requires at least Windows XP. Setup cannot continue."

What I am looking for now, is either:

- a way to get the installer to skip this check and install anyway  - or -
- a reason why this would not work (e.g. Delphi is using some Windows API that is not available in Windows 2000)

Comment: A comment, not an answer: this is a great reason to consider a virtual machine setup.  Isolation of the development environment, ready migration to a new physical machine, many other benefits.  XP in a VM would let you continue to use that Win2K machine.

Comment: I agree, in principle, but unfortunately the computer I am using is not up to running multiple virtual machines. If I can't get it to work with Windows 2000 I guess I will have to use a vm anyway...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to start the setup.exe with the /Win2K parameter. Maybe this helps. But I heard from a German forum that a user who installed Delphi 2010 into Windows 2000 had lots of problems with the IDE. So use the /Win2K parameter at your own risk.

And you must have at least .NET 2.0 **SP1** installed

Comment: Thanks, that got me over the "requires at least Windows XP" problem, we'll see whether it will work after the installation...

Comment: So far it seems to work. I have used it for about 4 hours without seeing any adverse effects. But I have by no means used all the features yet.

Comment: It is now several weeks later and I have not yet seen any problems. But again, I am not using all the features so there still might be something in store.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [minimum system requirements](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39754), Windows 2000 is not supported. They might use some XP+ specific API's these days, but then again they might not, as Delphi 2009 installed fine on Windows 2000.

The first thing you might want to check is if you have .Net (2.0 minimum) on your machine. According to the document linked above, they try to install The .Net 3.5 distributable otherwise, and that one definitely requires XP minimum.

Comment: Delphi 2009 is installed on that computer, so I should have .NET 2.0 already installed.

Comment: @dummzeuch: .NET 2.0 is not enough, they require .NET 3.5 which is not available for Windows 2000. I don't know what requires .NET 3.5 in the IDE but the installer has it as a prerequisite.

Comment: @Andreas: The installation notes (page I linked to) specifically states the requirement is 2.0, are the notes wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

windows 2000 is supported in Delphi 2010, check the following link:

[Target Windows 2000, XP, Vista, and Windows 7 from single source](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi)

I think the problem is from your pc, maybe because there are other versions are installed, can you post the message?

Comment: Notice the word "Target" in there?

Comment: I can also target Windows 95 with Delphi 2010 if I modify the System.pas. But targeting a system is something completely different than running the application (aka IDE) that targets the system.

Comment: sorry I didn't notice that, you are right +1 for both of you.

Comment: @Maroo: What is the wdosx target? Never heard of it, especially not in the context of Delphi. (Forget the question: I found DWPL on sourceforge. Apparently it never was supported officially.)